# How to add multiple values to a key in Properties file (Eclipse)?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I need to add a in a properties file keys that contain multiple values.

Is it possible to do this directly using Eclipse default libraries ?

Ex:

```
prop1=value1,value2,value3,value4
prop2=value1,value2,value3,value4
```

Comment: Yes it is try using `File` with `PrintWriter` and `Scanner` class...also these are not "eclipse" libraries they are java classes contained in java libraries.

Comment: And when I want to read it ? It is a way to recognize the values separated by comma ? (without parsing)

Comment: You can read with the `Scanner` and `File` classes not sure what you mean by "without parsing" you could create a properties object that contains your properties you would just need to give key and you would get your values you would just need to do `String.split(",")` to separate them.

Comment: Exactly, I don't want to do this, to parse the properties file.....I want to get all the properties directly without using string processing functions (that's why I asked about libraries)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Apache Commons Configuration](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/index.html), which has support for reading multiple property items:

```
PropertiesConfiguration config = new PropertiesConfiguration(yourFile);
List<Object> list = config.getList("prop1");

for (Object object : list) {
  System.out.println(object);
}
```

Output:

```
value1
value2
value3
value4
```

The new alpha release includes better support for typing (e.g. telling `PropertiesConfiguration` that you want to read a list of strings), but this isn't production ready yet.